# Django giving error ImportError: No module named 'corsheaders'

Tags: django, django-cors-headers

I am a newbie to Django and trying to enable CORS for my server. I couldn't find a built-in solution so I went with [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers). I am running my server in conda environment on python 3.5 in Ubuntu 15.04. So I installed it with pip3 install django-cors-header. When I do pip3 list it shoes django-cors-header installed at version 1.2.2. In my django app I did.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'polls',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

But when I run `python3 manage.py runserver` It stops saying `ImportError: No module named 'corsheaders'`. 
I have read all SO posts regarding it but none seem to solve my problem. 
Kindly help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Originally I did `pip3 install django-cors-headers`, instead by fluke I tried `pip install django-cors-headers` and voila it worked.

Hope it helps somebody

Comment: It helps. I had to instantiate my environment before it worked.

Comment: this answer could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744116/4026786

Answer (score 0):

I think you suppose to type the following command

`pip3 install django-cors-headers`

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, Pip was installing Packages Into global environment While VirtualEnv was Activated. So following command worked for me-

```
<path-to-your-env>/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me. I just forgot to run:

```
pipenv shell
```